# I have to create a program that compares SAT/ACT scores of two students. It technically works but it's missing something

Tags: java

So the program works, it just has a few things that I cant seem to fix: 
1) It feels like it can be simplified using more/different methods. I don't want ot be redundant.
2) At the end of the program, I can't get figure out how to turn the two final scores into "first" and "second" We aren't allowed to use several sopln's the program has to be able to identify which of the two scores is highest and be able to recognize if it was the first or second applicant. Here is the code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Admissions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        questionaire();
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        double first = designation(console, " first ");
        double second = designation(console, " second ");
        System.out.println("First applicant overall score = " + first);
        System.out.println("Second applicant overall score = " + second);
        System.out.println();

        double mostQualified = (Math.max(first,second));
        System.out.println("The " + mostQualified + " applicant is better qualified.");


    }

    // *** Methods ***
    public static void questionaire() {
        System.out.println(" This program compares two applicants to \n " +
                "determine which one is the stronger candidate. \n " +
                "For each candidate please provide either SAT \n " +
                "or ACT scores, plus a weighted GPA.");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static double designation(Scanner console, String x) {
        System.out.println("Information for the" + x +  "applicant: \n" +
                "do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores?");
        int answer = console.nextInt();
        if(answer == 2){
            return act(console);
        } else if (answer == 1){
            return sat(console);
        }else{
            return cheat();
        }
    }

    public static double designation2(Scanner console) {
        System.out.println("Information for the second applicant: \n" +
                "do you have 1) SAT scores or 2) ACT scores?");
        int answer2 = console.nextInt();
        if(answer2 == 2){
            return act(console);
        } else if (answer2 == 1){
            return sat(console);
        }else {
            return cheat();
        }
    }

    public static double act(Scanner console) {
        System.out.println("ACT English?");
        int actEnglish = console.nextInt();
        if ((actEnglish < 1) || (actEnglish > 36)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("ACT math?");
        int actMath = console.nextInt();
        if ((actMath < 1) || (actMath > 36)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("ACT reading?");
        int actReading = console.nextInt();
        if ((actReading < 1) || (actReading > 36)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("ACT science?");
        int actScience = console.nextInt();
        if ((actScience < 1) || (actScience > 36)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("Overall GPA?");
        double overallGPA = console.nextDouble();
        if ((overallGPA < 0.0) || (overallGPA > 4.0)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum GPA?");
        double maxGPA = console.nextDouble();
        if ((overallGPA < 0.0) || (overallGPA > 4.0)){
            return cheat();
        }
        int actScore = ((actScience - 1) + (actMath - 1) + (actReading - 1) + (actEnglish - 1) / (4*35));
        double actGPA = ((overallGPA) / (maxGPA) * 100);
        double finalActScore = (actScore + actGPA);
        return finalActScore;

    }
    public static double sat(Scanner console){
        System.out.println("SAT math?");
        int satMath = console.nextInt();
        if ((satMath < 200) || (satMath > 800)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("SAT verbal?");
        int satVerbal = console.nextInt();
        if ((satVerbal < 200) || (satVerbal > 800)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("Overall GPA?");
        double overallGPA = console.nextDouble();
        if ((overallGPA < 0.0) || (overallGPA > 4.0)){
            return cheat();
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum GPA?");
        double maxGPA = console.nextDouble();
        if ((overallGPA < 0.0) || (overallGPA > 4.0)){
            return cheat();
        }
        int satScore = ((satVerbal - 200) + (satMath - 200)) / (2*600);
        double satGPA = ((overallGPA) / (maxGPA) * 100);
        double finalSatScore = (satScore + satGPA);
        return finalSatScore;
    }
    public static double cheat(){
        System.out.println("YOU'RE A CHEATER.");
        System.exit(-1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Could you maybe formulate more specific questions? Also, "how to turn the two final scores into "first" and "second""; what would that mean?

Comment: I think your code would be easier to handle if you didn’t used only static methods and instead made use of class variables and methods

Answer (score 1):

**1) You can factorize part of your code**

You already did it with your `designation` method which is good. You can delete the `designation2` method.

In your `act` method. There is 4 repetitions of this test :

```
 if ((value < 1) || (value > 36)){
       return cheat();
 }
```

You can factorise it inside a method like this :

```
private void checkScoreForAct(int value) {
    if ((value < 1) || (value > 36)){
        cheat();
    }
}
```

Then in your `act` method, you call it to check the ACT score for the english, math, reading and science.

```
System.out.println("ACT English?");
int actEnglish = console.nextInt();
checkScoreForAct(actEnglish);
```

That's one exemple but you could also factorise the part where you calculate the overall GPA (present in the `act` and `sat` method).

Same for when you calculate the `satGPA` and `actGPA`, you could put this logic in a method.

**2) How to turn the two final scores into *first* and *second* ?**

You can easily check who is the applicant who have the best score.

```
public static String FIRST = "first";
public static String SECOND = "second";
public static String BOTH = "both";


String bestApplicant;
if (first == second) {
    bestApplicant = BOTH;
} else if (first > second) {
    bestApplicant = FIRST;
} else {
    bestApplicant = SECOND;
}

double maxScore = (Math.max(first,second));
if (bestApplicant.equals(BOTH)) {
    System.out.println("Both applicant are equally qualified with a score of " + maxScore);
} else {
    System.out.println("The " + bestApplicant + " applicant is better qualified with a score of " + maxScore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your parameters exclude this, as what you say you aren't allowed to do makes no sense to me.  Here's what you seem to be asking how to do:

```
String mostQualified = (first > second)? "first" : "second";
double bestScore = Math.max(first, second);
System.out.println("The " + mostQualified
        + " applicant is better qualified, with a score of "
        + bestScore);
```

Sample result:

```
The first applicant is better qualified, with a score of 88.1
```